# Button in ContentView causes crash in MonoTouch runtime. Bug in Monotouch 4.0?

Tags: c#, ios, ipad, xamarin.ios

My application worked fine in MT 3.0. Now when I upgraded. I am seeing errors when a button is in a ContentView. Crashes happen when the button is clicked. Code:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPa
    float width = tableView.Bounds.Width - 70;

    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(kCellIdentifier);
    //if (cell == null)
    //{
    cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, kCellIdentifier);
    // }

    var behavior = tvc.behaviors.ElementAt(indexPath.Row);
    cell.TextLabel.Text = behavior.Name;
    cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(22f);
    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = behavior.Definition;
    var view = UIButton.FromType(UIButtonType.Custom);
    view.Tag = indexPath.Row;
    view.SetImage(UIImage.FromBundle("Images/plus.png"), UIControlState.Normal);
    view.Frame = new RectangleF(width - 50, 10, 50, 50);

    view.TouchUpInside += IncrementBehavior;

    var label = new UILabel(new RectangleF(width - 80, 10, 50, 50));
    label.Text = behavior.CurrentCount.ToString();
    label.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
    label.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(24f);
    cell.ContentView.AddSubview(view);
    cell.ContentView.AddSubview(label);
    //cell.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;)

    return cell;
}

void IncrementBehavior(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var button = (UIButton)sender;
    var tag = button.Tag;
    var behavior = tvc.behaviors[tag];

    var indexpath = NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(tag, 0);
    var newBehavior = Repository.GetBehavior(behavior.Id);
    newBehavior.CurrentCount++;
    Repository.Update(newBehavior);
    tvc.behaviors[tag] = newBehavior;


    tvc.TableView.ReloadRows(new[] { indexpath }, UITableViewRowAnimation.None);

}
```

I am getting these Errors interchangeably:

```
Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[__NSCFSet BridgeSelector]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5c3c570
```

AND

```
No constructor found for MonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlEventProxy::.ctor(System.IntPtr)
```

Comment: I hope someone here has an answer, because you're sure not going to get any useful help from Attachmate...

Comment: Would you mind providing me with a self-contained test case that exhibits this problem?

Comment: Something very simmilar happend to me when I was assigning the same even handler for touchupinside twice for a button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure if this is the problem, but when I upgraded to 4.0, I also got some random crashes.  It turned out that the 4.0 GC is more aggressive, and that things I was previously getting away with were no longer kosher.

In particular, if I had a event handler assigned to a button, I needed to be sure the button was declared at the class level.  If it was declared locally in the method, the GC would purge the reference when it went out of scope, and then later when the event handler tried to fire, it's reference was no longer there.

So try moving the declaration of your button outside of your method.

Comment: Well I have one button for each row, should i store it in a collection of some sort?

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thanks...this is EXTREMELY annoying though. I have this kind of code everywhere. Any other ways to do it?

Comment: That's the only way I'm aware of, and given the current non-state of MT, I doubt a better workaround or fix will be forthcoming.

Comment: MT 4.0 merely forced the GC to run more often while running on the simulator to show potential problems.