# What does it mean if the garbage collector is "more aggressive" in Monotouch 4?

Tags: .net, mono, garbage-collection, xamarin.ios, boehm-gc

I stumbled about this question: [Button in ContentView causes crash in MonoTouch runtime. Bug in Monotouch 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037792/button-in-contentview-causes-crash-in-monotouch-runtime-bug-in-monotouch-4-0) and the inquirer has problems with Monotouch's "more aggressive" garbage collector.

- Can somebody explain why in the inquirer's case the error is issued (what gets collected and why?)?
- What does "more aggressive" mean? What are the traps I can fall into? What should I avoid?
- With regards to iOS5: Apple claims with iOS5 the app will get one memory warning and then it will get killed. Unlike any other version before, where an app received three warnings. What does that mean for Monotouch? How will it deal with this behavior?

Maybe one of the Xamarin team can sum up some dos and don'ts and give a good explanation?

I am currently upgrading from MT 3.2.6 to MT 4.1 and would like to go through my code and check what has to be changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We found that sometimes developers would run into strange problems like dialogs would sometimes stay on the screen, and sometimes they would vanish without leaving a trace and with no explanation of why this happened.

This typically happened when you created an UIAlertView and kept no references to it, so as far as MonoTouch was concerned, that object was garbage (you did not reference it from your code, so you did not have a use for it).

But whether the dialog vanished from your screen immediately or later depended on whether the Garbage Collector's heuristics had determined that it was time to run a collection.  If you had created a dialog just after a collection, chances are, your dialog would stay on the screen.   But if you were very close to a collection, or if you had a background process consuming memory, then the GC would be triggered.

This in general was confusing to users, "why are things vanishing randomly".  The answer was: if you did not keep a reference to it, the GC assumed you did not care.

To make this more clear to our users, when running MonoTouch on debug mode on the simulator (and there is a command line option to control that for any builds), we added a thread on the simulator that continuously calls GC.Collect() every few seconds.   This makes it more obvious that you might have not kept a reference to a dialog of yours.

Later on, we found out that a very useful and common pattern was to keep two kinds of dialog boxes around that really have no use other than their side effects: UIAlertView and UIActionSheet.   We altered MonoTouch so that it internally keeps references to those two until dismissed.

So we ended up with the best of both worlds: during the development cycle you catch earlier missing references to objects that you need, and we took care of the two most common cases that are only useful for their side effects.

Comment: Can you point out what gets collected in the example I referenced? Is it the delegate that vanishes? Because the cell is on screen, the button is in the cell and the button has a delegate assigned - what would possibly get collected?

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of good questions.

About the aggressiveness, a Garbage Collector **can** collect objects once there are no more references to them. If it does this slowly (call this *passive*) you *might* never notice some bugs you have in your software.

OTOH running applications (multitasking) under low-memory condition brings it's own problems. So collecting more often (call this *aggressive*) will reclaim memory faster and *can* help overall performance. However you are more likely to hit (your own) **bugs** in cases where objects are still used after no *managed* references are held.

Comment: But if we take the inquirer's issue: what is wrong there? Why can't his event handler not be called? The cell is there, the button is in the cell and the button has a handler. Why would anything be collected?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if the fact that an object has a handler/delegate assigned should count as an active reference from the GC point of view?  There may be unintended consequences of doing that.  I'd be interesting in hearing Xamarin's take on that idea.

Comment: It's the other way round. Your handler/delegate cannot be found anymore. The button is still there, I assume you can see it in your UI. But that does not make it any clearer. But yeah, I'd like to hear Xamarin on this one.

Comment: There was some reasoning behind answering only part of the original question ;-) and I'll try answer others when I have time (including reading the source code linked). But my point stands: variations in the garbage collection frequency can expose/hide bugs in applications.

Comment: A delegate is a reference to a method of an object, so yes it is an active reference. The reference is one way. From the one holding the reference to the object being referenced in the delegate. So adding a delegate to the TouchUpInside event from the button does not keep the button alive. The button does keep the object in the delegate alive. Once the button is not referenced anymore it could be GCed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298261/do-event-handlers-stop-garbage-collection-from-occuring

Comment: Yeah, but the button is in a cell, the cell is in a list and the list is on the screen. How much more existence is necessary to have a valid reference? Or is the issue coming from reusing the cells?

Answer (score 1):

So after reading the code I could not find why this would be a problem (and there was not enough code to try it quickly). Now if the crash was related to UIButton then AddSubView should have logically made the reference. Reading the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) confirmed that to be the case (emphasis is mine):

> The view to be added. **This view is retained by the receiver**. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.

A bit of googling got me to [bug #670294](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=670294#c22) which links to a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902967/uiview-events-and-garbage-collection) very similar to the one you linked. Comment #22 describe a workaround for this issue (it's a bug) and is fixed in MonoTouch 4.1.

Right now I can't tell you it that's a GC issue affecting MonoTouch itself (same rules applies to everybody) or unrelated. I would *guess* it's related since keeping another reference was cited as the solution - *but since I'm curious I'll look at the fix and add a comment later* ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm the one who said the GC was "more aggressive"..  That's my term - I think Miguel views it a little differently.  My interpretation was based on the fact that things you could get away with in MT3 no longer work (or are not as reliable) in MT4.

Comment: Still I don't see what would be wrong with your example code.

Comment: FWIW I like the "aggressive" term myself :-) just like the "get away with in MT3" is another good one. However I dislike the "not as reliable" since we should do our best to _never_ rely on such behaviors. It's just like ignoring threading issues, such cases always come back to haunt you later ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Another answer...

> With regards to iOS5: Apple claims with iOS5 the app will get one
>   memory warning and then it will get killed. Unlike any other version
>   before, where an app received three warnings. What does that mean for
>   Monotouch? How will it deal with this behavior?

I won't talk about iOS5 (since I don't track what's public and what's not). Since you cannot know how low memory could be (or required by something else) there's no point in having very complex strategy to free memory. The user needs it elsewhere, give it back :)

The way to deal with this is to override **DidReceiveMemoryWarning** and free **everything** you can, like:

- call [GC.Collect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357.aspx) - it's one of the few, right time to call this;
- clear any cache(s) you have (e.g. downloaded data, anything else you can re-compute later if needed)

Comment: I think GC.Collect is called automatically if DidReceivememoryWarning fires. At least I Would really expect it to.