# Why MonoTouch runtime crash with UIAlertView?

Tags: c#, ios5, xamarin.ios

I have a legacy C# class that extends `UIAlertView` for prompting the user to enter an IP address. It also will persist the IP address and load it as the default entry value.

The original code hacked the iOS4.x `UIAlertView` to add a text field and it had several layout problems. I converted the code to use the iOS5 `UIAlertView`'s `AlertViewStyle` setting and everything worked fine.

I was asked to enable the **Done** key on the popup keyboard so that it could be a shortcut to the **Connect** button. I added code as follows to the class's constructor:

```
public AddressAlertView()
{
    AddButton("Cancel");
    AddButton("Connect");
    AlertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput;

    // NEW - get input text field, enable Done on the keyboard and
    // allow Done to be the same as the Connect button
    UITextField fld = GetTextField(0);
    fld.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
    fld.ShouldReturn = (textField) =>
    {
        DismissWithClickedButtonIndex(1, true);
        return textField.ResignFirstResponder();
    };
    // *** end of new code ***

    // restore saved IP address
    string savedAddress = NSUserDefault.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(AddressKey);
    if (savedAddress != null)
        fld.Text = savedAddress;
}
```

The class gets used like so:

```
....
AddressAlertView addrPrompt = new AddressAlertView();
addrPrompt.Title = "IP Address";
addrPrompt.Message = "Enter address";
addrPrompt.Dismissed += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.ButtonIndex == 1)
    {
        // use IP address...
        ....
    }
};
addrPrompt.Show();
....
```

Now the problem. When running this code, the `AddressAlertView` shows the popup dialog correctly and everything works as before. However, if I tap **Done** on the keyboard, the app bombs out in `UIAlertView`.

I tried moving the new code to the `public override void LayoutSubviews()` method, but it still crashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, still learning comment formatting. Figured it out. In looking at the trace dump output from MonoTouch, there was a mention of an invalid object. Instead of getting the text field as a local variable, I save a reference to it as an instance variable:`private UITextField _addressTextField = null;` I changed the code in the constructor to `_addressTextField = GetTextField(0);`. That solved the crash. The local `UITextField` variable was undoubtedly getting GC'd, causing the crash when `ShouldReturn` lambda expression was getting called.

Comment: You should make your explanation an answer and accept your own answer to help others who look for a solution to a similar problem. This is perfectly okay and wanted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the AddressAlertView as a class member:

```
AddressAlertView addrPrompt;
public void DoSomething()
{

    addrPrompt = new AddressAlertView();
    //etc

}
```

The problem in this type of situations (I had many similar with UIAlertViews) is that the AddressAlertView object is GC'd and the event handler causes the crash. To make sure this is the issue, do not change anything, just remove/comment the `addrPrompt.Dismissed += ...` line and test it again. If it does not crash, than this is the solution.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered something similar. See my comment above. I didn't have to make my `AddressAlertView` a class member.

Comment: The UIAlertView is one of the classes that Monotouch handles smart. You don't have to hold a class reference. MT will take care of this internally.

Comment: @Krumelur Is this for sure? I had lots of issues with UIAlertView a few months back. Now that you've mentioned this, I'll check again with the latest stable version.

Comment: Yep, this is sure. Read Miguel's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113145/what-does-it-mean-if-the-garbage-collector-is-more-aggressive-in-monotouch-4

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's documentation, you should not be subclassing UIAlertView:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Comment: Yup, I know the sage words of Apple in this matter. I inherited this code, so I had to make it work. A better way to do this class would be to encapsulate `UIAlertView` rather than inherit from it. BTW, all your work on MonoTouch rocks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. In looking at the trace dump output from MonoTouch, there was a mention of an invalid object. Instead of getting the text field as a local variable, I save a reference to it as an instance variable:

```
private UITextField _addressTextField = null;
```

I changed the code in the constructor to:

```
_addressTextField = GetTextField(0);
```

Voila! That solved the crash. The local UITextField variable was undoubtedly getting GC'd, causing the crash when the `ShouldReturn` lambda expression was getting called.